# EventSource is not logging

Tags: c#, prism, mef, bootstrapping, semantic-logging

I am using the Semantic Logging Application Block, and I have the following two EventSource based classes (inner constant classes omitted for brevity:

```
[EventSource(Name = EventSourceNames.Prism)]
public sealed class PrismEventSource: EventSource
{
  public static PrismEventSource Log = new PrismEventSource();
  [Event(1, Keywords = EventKeywords.None, Level = EventLevel.Informational)]
  public void PrismEvent(string message, Category category, Priority priority)
  {
    if (IsEnabled())
    {
      WriteEvent(1, message, category);
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
[EventSource(Name = EventSourceNames.Application)]
public sealed class ApplicationEventSource : EventSource
{
  public static ApplicationEventSource Log = new ApplicationEventSource();
  [Event(2, Message = "Duplicate menu item: {0}", Keywords = Keywords.Menu, Level = EventLevel.LogAlways, Task = Tasks.ImportMenu)]
  public void DuplicateMenuItem(string menuItemPath)
  {
    if (IsEnabled())
    {
      WriteEvent(2, menuItemPath);
    }
  }
}
```

I have a project wide singleton listener for both:

```
RollingLog = RollingFlatFileLog.CreateListener("XTimeDev.log", 2048, "yyyyMMdd HHmmss", RollFileExistsBehavior.Overwrite, RollInterval.None);
RollingLog.EnableEvents(EventSourceNames.Prism, EventLevel.LogAlways);
RollingLog.EnableEvents(EventSourceNames.Application, EventLevel.LogAlways);
```

Yet when I try and log from my Application source, nothing appears in the log file:

```
try
{
  Current.RegisterMenuItem(xtimeItem);
}
catch (ArgumentException ax)
{
  ApplicationEventSource.Log.DuplicateMenuItem(ax.Message);
}
```

All I see in my log file is the startup events Prism logs through its event source, the one I give it in `MefBootstrapper.CreateLogger`:

```
class BootLogger : ILoggerFacade
{
  public void Log(string message, Category category, Priority priority)
  {
    PrismEventSource.Log.PrismEvent(message, category, priority);
  }
}
```

Why should only the `PrismEventSource` and not the `ApplicationEventSource` write to the file?

Comment: Have you verified that `IsEnabled` is returning true in the `DuplicateMenuItem` method?

Comment: @Matt, indeed I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method signature doesn't match the number of parameters you pass to `WriteEvent`.

If you change it to this it should work:

```cs
public void PrismEvent(string message, Category category, Priority priority)
{
  if (IsEnabled())
  {
    WriteEvent(1, message, category, priority);
    //                                 ^  ^
  }
}
```

Matching signatures are required for it to work properly.

---

You can detect future issues like this in a unit test by using [`EventSourceAnalyzer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.semanticlogging.utility.eventsourceanalyzer.inspectall.aspx). I recommend using it, as it will find these errors much quicker.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `EventSourceAnalyszer`, but `WriteEvent` isn't aware of how many parameters are passed to `PrismEvent`, so it cannot detect the mismatch. It has overloads that allow from 1 to 3 string parameters, and even one that takes `params object[]`. It is also the only one that is actually working. As I said, "All I see in my log file is the startup events Prism logs through its event source", that being the one you cite. Thanks also for pointing out my little bug.

Comment: A normal C# method couldn't detect that, but the event source can, and it will cause problems. I think it goes by the registry for event signatures. Also, it could be that the Prism event source is somehow breaking the Application event source, which is enabled after it.

Comment: Other things that come to my head: `Log` is a field, where it's usually a property. You might have public methods or properties (or even events!) that are not events, and are not marked with `[NonEvent]`. I know this can cause errors.